# getting titlesec package to respect title font, etc in style file

Tags: titlesec

I am using a `.sty` file submitted by a journal which puts the section headers in capitals format. However, when i use the following

```
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*1}{*1}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*1}{*1}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*1}{*1}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{*1}{*1}
\titlespacing{\subparagraph}{0pt}{*1}{*1}
```

this formatting is replaced by a format of first letter in capitals, the rest in small lettering. Is there a way to get `\titlesec` to respect the fonts, lettering, etc of the style file?

Sorry if this question is not very clear.  I am happy to clarify further.

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: It's hard to say why titlesec doesn't respect the formatting of the journal without knowing what's in the journal .sty file. Maybe the order in which the packages are loaded matters.

Comment: If you use the style for the journal, you should stick to what *they* want: it's their journal and they decide the spacing of titles.

Comment: Sorry, here is the style file.  This is an unofficial style file which respects requirements of the journals and so is very helpful. The journal itself has no style files, just guidelines on formatting of references, section titles, etc. Here is the website having the style file:     http://stat.duke.edu/programs/gcc/Styles/asa.sty Thanks again for the help, and the formatting tip!